# Zero knowledge commitment to a "strictly positive integer" and "nonzero element"

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, zero-knowledge

Suppose I want to commit to the following information:

- I have an integer $i\in\mathbb Z$ and I want to commit to $i$ *and* that $i\gneq 0$, without revealing $i$.
- I have an element of a prime field $x\in\mathbb F_p$.  I want to commit to $x$ *and* that it's nonzero, without revealing $x$.

Can anyone advise on the current state of the art?

My question seems to be a special case of both of these questions:

- [Zero-knowledge proof of committed value](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/91478/zero-knowledge-proof-of-committed-value)
- [Zero knowledge proof for sign of message value](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42019/zero-knowledge-proof-for-sign-of-message-value)

but what I take from these answers is that it's quite complicated.  For instance [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42029/115752) runs to multiple pages.  So, I am particularly interested in *simple* (if not necessarily optimal) schemes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> 2. I have an element of a prime field $x\in\mathbb F_p$.  I want to commit to $x$ *and* that it's nonzero, without revealing $x$.

Actually, that part is pretty easy (as long as $p$ is of reasonable size, say $> 2^{256}$).

First, we pick a $q = kp + 1$ prime which is at least 2048 bits long (to make the discrete log problem hard) [1].

Then, we use a Pedersen commitment of $x$, that is, we pick elements $g, h$ of the subgroup of size $p$ where $\log_g h$ is unknown, and a commitment is $C = g^xh^r \bmod q$, for a random value $r$.

To prove that, for $C$, the committed value $x \ne 0$, we select a random exponent $s \ne 0$, compute $A = C^s \bmod p$ and $B = g^{xs} \bmod p$, and publish $A, B$ along with zero knowledge proofs that:

- We know the value $s$ for which $A = C^s$
- We know the value $t$ for which $B = g^t$
- We know the value $u$ for which $AB^{-1} = h^u$

These can be generated by issuing Schnorr proofs of knowledge.

To verify this zero knowledge proof, we would check that $A, B$ are in the subgroup of size $p$ (that is, $A^p = 1, B^p = 1$), that $B \ne 1$ (which implies that $t \ne 0$), and verify the three zero knowledge subproofs.

This works because the verify can see that $(g^xh^r)^s g^{-t} = h^u$, that is, $g^{xs-t}h^{rs} = h^u$.  Because the prover knows the values $x, s, t, r, u$ but not the value $g^z = h$, we must have $xs-t = 0$ and $rs = u$ (otherwise the prover could reconstruct $z$).  And, because $t \ne 0$, we must have $xs \ne 0$, hence $x \ne 0$.

---

[1]: I do this in the mod $q$ group because it is easy to construct such a group with a $p$ sized subgroup.  If you happen to have an elliptic curve with such a subgroup, you can use that as well...

Comment: Very nice. Essentially, you've blinded the Pedersen commitment, in order to be able to demonstrate that it takes a semi-Pedersen commitment to a value that is not zero to cancel out the amount on G.